# Locally nilpotent derivations on noncommutative rings

Tags: reference-request

I am interested on LNDs on noncommutative rings, specially noncommutative polynomial rings. It is being hard to find via Google. Anyone know any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a reference: http://www.math.wayne.edu/~lml/lmlnotes.pdf

These are some lecture notes by L. Makar-Limanov.